# Perform algebraic operations with nested dictionaries using "lambda" and "dictionary comprehension"?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, compression, list-comprehension

The problem of multiplying two "simple" dictionaries with the help of `lambda`, I decided as follows:

```
v1={'product1': '100', 'product2': '120'}
v2={'product1': '3', 'product2': '2'}

foo = lambda dct_1, dct_2: {key: int(dct_2[key]) * int(dct_1[key]) for key in dct_2}

foo(v1, v2)
# Out: {'product1': 300, 'product2': 240}
```

How can I multiply two nested dictionaries in the same way?

```
V={'id1': [{'product1': '1', 'product2': '2'}],'id2': [{'product1': '3', 'product2': '4'}]}
Z={'id1': [{'благо1': '10', 'благо2': '25'}], 'id2': [{'product1': '20', 'product2': '15'}]}
```

The answer should be as follows:

```
Out:={'id1': [{'product1': '10', 'product2': '50'}], 'id2': [{'product1': '60', 'product2': '60'}]}
```

I'm using Python3.

Comment: Why do you have lists inside V, Z? They are not nested dictionaries in this way

Comment: It's logical ... maybe not quite nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will omit the `lambda` because that comprehension is already quite long, but basically you could use:

```
{outerkey: [{innerkey: int(V[outerkey][0][innerkey])*int(Z[outerkey][0][innerkey]) 
             for innerkey in V[outerkey][0]}] 
 for outerkey in V}
```

Giving me:

```
{'id1': [{'product1': 10, 'product2': 50}],
 'id2': [{'product1': 60, 'product2': 60}]}
```

Note: I assumed that the dictionaries had the same keys:

```
V={'id1': [{'product1': '1', 'product2': '2'}],'id2': [{'product1': '3', 'product2': '4'}]}
Z={'id1': [{'product1': '10', 'product2': '25'}], 'id2': [{'product1': '20', 'product2': '15'}]}
```

Comment: Yes, the keys are the same.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Yaroslav I'm glad it worked. Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer